# Insert Autocomplete Search Bar in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I am building a very simple landing page for a project on Squarespace.
The only *sophisticated* feature would be an input field (like a search bar) that shows a guess of the word based on letter matches given a list of words (approximately 100).

It seems to me, from reading similar questions and researching, that adapting a script from jsfiddle could do the trick:

The HTML part:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-3">
    <form class="navbar-form" id="theSearchForm" name="theSearchForm" role="search" method="get" action="yoursearchfilescriptgoeshere">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:document.theSearchForm.submit();">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
```

The JS part:

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

Although Squarespace is supposed to allow for code snippets (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) to be added as blocks, I cannot get it working.

There is only one field per code snippet in Squarespace, thus:

1. should that mean I must insert all codes (HTML and JavaScript) next to each other in the code snippet field (including obviously the `<script>` tags on each side of the JavaScript codes)?
2. or should I insert them as different blocks *as they would "automatically call each other" if this makes sense*?

I believe I would also need to include the following jquery.min.js, jquery-ui-git.js, bootstrap.min.css yet I have some hope that once I understand what I am doing wrong in the above I would be able to apply it here too.

Please let me know if anything is unclear and if you need more information.

Comment: Are you including a reference to jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: I believe I should, right?